# NebulaGraph Database error `The leader has changed. Try again later`

Tags: nebula-graph

This error happens when I insert some vertices in to Nebula Graph (v3.0.0). What does this error mean? What can I do except for retry?

I'm working on my ubuntu laptop (HDD).

I checked the manual https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/20.appendix/0.FAQ/

My partiton number is 100? Is that too large?

Comment: Have you provided enough detail for others to [reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reset the environment and changed the partition number to 5. It looks ok by now.
I think it's the heartbeat problem.